# Actionscript: Making pseudostreaming seeking faster

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming

I was trying to make seeking of Netstream faster setting `NetStream.bufferTime=0.1`, but it seems it's ignoring it.

I was trying to find an answer in video conversion process. Setting `avconv -g 25`, but this helped a only a bit.

If i'll increase amount of keyframes, will that improve seeking time?

I want to make video start instantly, how to achieve this via flash player?

Comment: More info about server and protocol with stream? you use osmf or own player?

Comment: What is value that you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using my own player. I want to achieve smooth rewind as it's implemented in html5 players. Instant playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having more keyFrame in your video won't change the seeking performance. It only affects the precision of the seeking.

Seeking performance issue might be due to your streaming server. Have you tried to read your stream with a different player (vlc), to check if it's more a player problem than a server one ?

**UPDATE :**

take a look at this module for nginx :
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html.
Even if i never tried it, it should do the job...

Comment: Nope haven't, only used stream via flash player in the webpage.

Comment: Nginx is saying that it's transfering about 5-6 mb of metadata.

Comment: Did you try to seek at 0 and note the delay. And then, seek far in the file and note the delay. If your server implements seeking, you should have the same delay. If not, the file is downloaded at each request and the player waits for the good keyframe to start playing...

Comment: i'm using nginx mp4 module.

Comment: The delay is much lesser when rewinding to the end of movie and much greater when it's closer to the start.

Comment: "player waits for the good keyframe to start playing" That's what i was seeking for. Could you tell a bit more about it? What do you mean by "good" keyframe? How to increase good keyframes amount? :)

Comment: Videos are made of frames and keyframes. To sayt it simply, keyframes are full image frame and the other frames encode only the delta part between 2 frames (really simple view ^^). But a keyframe is much bigger than the other one. Decoders needs to start from a key frame to compute the following frames. Increasing key frame frequency must be done at the encoding.

Comment: "The delay is much lesser when rewinding...". Are you sure that seeking to the end is faster than playing from 0 ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure about rewinding. About this - "Increasing key frame frequency must be done at the encoding", how to implement that via libav avconv conversion tool? I could not found in their docs. 

5-6 seconds rewinding at the start

This is closer to the end: 481 ms, 415 ms

Comment: you can have a look here using ffmpeg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117757/how-to-control-key-frame-generation-of-ffmpeg but i don't believe that it is your problem. Did you try with another player ? try vlc to check if it's a problem of your flash player.