# Accuracy issue in jump to particular section of video in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

in my app i want to add feature . swipe on video take the video to next 2 sec from current playback time. but my player not doing this accurate and exact according to time which i pass to function it jump the current play back time at any where else. i already search a lot and found may be this is due to key-frame of my video i think i need to increase key-frame of video if yes 
then (1) what is the best way to increase key-frame of video? 
if this issue can solve without increasing key-frame then
(2) how can i do this ?

here is my code

```
-(void) handleOneFingerSwipeRight
{
    if(labelTimer.isValid)
        [labelTimer invalidate];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(signleTap) object:nil];
    [videoPlayer pause];
    double d = 0;
    d = floor([videoPlayer currentPlaybackTime]);
    d = d+2.0;
    NSLog(@"current time %f",floor([videoPlayer currentPlaybackTime]));
    NSLog(@"new time %f",d);
    [videoPlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime:d];
    [videoPlayer play];
    [self setLable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Adaptive Forward %f",d]];
}
```

Comment: As you found out already, the encoding plays a key role. Question is, how do you currently encode your video?

Comment: In case you used ffmpeg (which I strongly advise you to do), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14121293/91282) should help.

Comment: i am not encoding write now i just capture video from IOS device OR import from gallery so how to increase key-frame of video OR how to Encode video