# Set -keyint_min ffmpeg

Tags: objective-c, c, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm converting an mp4 video to HLS of 10 seconds duration in my iOS app. I need to set the keyint_min (FFmpeg) Minimum GOP length, the minimum distance between I-frames and gop_size. I don't know where to set these values within the ffmpeg wrapper class. Please suggest me some methods to set these values.

Comment: what library are you using for the wrapper?

Comment: Hi Rogerdpack, I'm using this library: https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper

Comment: according to the readme "Converts file at inputPath to a new file at outputPath using the parameters specified in the options dictionary" so I'd add keyint_min to that dictionary with your value.

Comment: Hi Rogerdpack, thank you for your reply, I tried that too, still getting segments with more than 10 seconds.

Comment: hmm where are you seeing documentation on "keyint_min" I know there's a "-g" parameter, and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 show a -x264opts keyint=123:min-keyint=20 style parameter, but I don't see a keyint_min...

Comment: @ Rogerdpack, please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117757/how-to-control-key-frame-generation-of-ffmpeg