# is there a way to control the extraction of key frame using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

the situation is i get 8 frames with the default threshold for scenecut detection.as the key frames i get is not representive enough .so i want to turn down the threhold to get more key-frames.but i use the -g and -sc_threshold arguments in my command(reference:[How to control key-frame generation of ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117757/how-to-control-key-frame-generation-of-ffmpeg)) ,it donot work well.i still get the same 8 frames without any change.any ideas?

Comment: PICT_TYPE_I should output only key frames (I frames). if you run ffprobe -show_frames on your video does it list any frames that you did not get thumbnails for?

Comment: my last comment should say 'does it list any I frames that you did not get thumbnails for?'

Comment: no,the situation is i get 8 frames with the default threshold for scenecut detection.as the key frames i get is not representive enough .so i want to turn down the threhold to get more key-frames.but i use the -g and -sc_threshold arguments in my command(reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117757/how-to-control-key-frame-generation-of-ffmpeg) ,it donot work well.i still get the same 8 frames without any change.any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. In an encoded video stream, a stored frame is either a keyframe or it isn't. You can't designate other frames to be treated as keyframes. The command in the original version of your Q will extract all I-frames. Those may not match your intuition of which frames ought to be keyframes, since the encoder may have decided otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could output an iframes list and use it with some script.

```
$ ffprobe -show_packets -print_format compact input.mkv 2>/dev/null | egrep -n flags=K | cut -d: -f 1 > iframes
```